# AutoMapper inheritance and Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, automapper

I've been looking over how to use Inheritance in `AutoMapper` but I'm struggling to get it working fully with `Linq`. Here is my code:

I have defined my mappings here:

```
CreateMap<Article, ArticleDetailsViewModel>()
    .Include<Article, ArticleNewsItemDetailsViewModel();

CreateMap<Article, ArticleNewsItemDetailsViewModel>();
```

`ArticleDetailsViewModel` is a base class of `ArticleNewsItemDetailsViewModel`.

Now here lies the problem, if I had:

```
CreateMap<ArticleNewsItem, ArticleNewsItemDetailsViewModel>();
```

All of the properties in the view model would automatically map because they are the same name as their Linq object counterpart. **However**, because I am using the `Article => ArticleNewsItemDetailsViewModel` mapping this is not possible, instead I would have to define each one as:

```
.ForMember(x => x.Property1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ArticleNewsItem.Property1)
```

I thought about moving all properties from `ArticleNewsItemDetailsViewModel` into a new view model and having that class a property within the `ArticleNewsItemDetailsViewModel` and as long as there is a mapping between those two objects then it will work, but it doesn't feel very clean.

Is there any way to avoid having to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have the following classes:

```
    public class Article
    {
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
        public ArticleNewsItem ArticleNewsItem { get; set; }
    }

    public class ArticleDetailsViewModel
    {
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class ArticleNewsItemDetailsViewModel : ArticleDetailsViewModel
    {
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
        public string Prop3 { get; set; }
    }

    public class ArticleNewsItem
    {
        public string Prop3 { get; set; }
    }
```

The mapping should look like below:

```
var res = Mapper.Map<Article, ArticleNewsItemDetailsViewModel>(_article);
Mapper.Map(_article.ArticleNewsItem, res);
```

Moreover you can create [custom type converter](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters) to avoid writing these two lines every time you need to map `Article` to `ArticleNewsItemDetailsViewModel`.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I am over simplifying this in my head but can't you simply add the direct mapping you mention:

```
CreateMap<ArticleNewsItem, ArticleNewsItemDetailsViewModel>();
```

To me this is the simplest and cleanest solution...

**EDIT**
Sorry, I misunderstood. You can't map an object to a nested property without creating a custom map via .ConstructUsing() or .ConvertUsing() methods (or doing it the untidy way)...

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Article, ArticleNewsItemDetailsViewModel>().ConstructUsing(ConstructItem)
```

..Then create your method to build the ArticleNewsItemDetailsViewModel...

```
private static ArticleNewsItemDetailsViewModel ConstructItem(Article source)
    {
        var newsItem = new ArticleNewsItem
                           {
                               Prop1 = source.Prop1,
                               Prop2 = source.Prop2
                           };

        var result = new ArticleNewsItemDetailsViewModel()
                         {
                             ArticleNewsItem = newsItem
                         };

        return result;
    }
```

However I would still recommend re implementing your solution so you are mapping 'like for like'. Here is a good example: http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Nested%20Mappings

Comment: I don't think this works because its a property mapping to a property within a nested object. Not a property that is an object mapping to a nested object

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.  You can't map an object to a nested property without creating a custom map via `.ConstructUsing()` or `.ConvertUsing()` methods.  You should really be mapping like for like.  Here is a good example: http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Nested%20Mappings

Comment: Thanks for understanding the question. However, there is no need to define the mapping within ConstructItem as that can be done using .ForMember and accessing nested properties.

Comment: Indeed it can, however I felt this was a neater solution to your problem. The heart of the issue is that you ate trying to map an inner property to an outer instance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the required properties are in Article you could create a [Custom Value Resolver](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Value%20Resolvers) to do this e.g.

```
public class ArticleNewsItemResolver : ValueResolver<Article, ArticleNewsItem>
{
    protected override ArticleNewsItem ResolveCore(Article source)
    {
        return Mapper.DynamicMap<Article, ArticleNewsItem>(source);
    }
}
...

CreateMap<Article, ArticleNewsItemDetailsViewModel>()
    .ForMember(src => src.NewsItem, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<ArticleNewsItemResolver>());
```